# implement __autoload in a Class

Tags: php, autoload

Is there a way I can define `__autoload` in a class, so whenever I access an undefined class PHP will run the `__autoload` class method?

```
<?php 
class Test {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Instantiating ', __CLASS__, "\n";
    }

    public function __autoload($className) {
        echo "Loading $className\n";
        require_once($className . '.php');
    }

    public function test() {
        $test = new AnotherClass();
    }
}

$bill = new Test();
$bill->test();
```

AnotherClass.php:

```
<?php
class AnotherClass {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Instantiating ', __CLASS__, "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Instantiating Test
> Loading AnotherClass
> Instantiating AnotherClass
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `__autoload` function must be global.

However, `SPL` has a way to register any *callable* as an autoload function: [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). It does not make much sense to use a class method though - you'd probably just create the instance, register the method and never use that instance again.

Comment: To tell PHP where to find the class that `__autoload` will be defined in? ;)

Comment: Ok it's a global function. Get it now

Answer (score 1):

This page has information on how to implement autoload in classes (PHP Manual) [spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: Nice one; didn't think about SPL. However, before PHP 5.3 SPL was optional and thus possibly not available - especially on shared hosting you don't necessarily have a recent PHP version.

Comment: True. But you can always built-in a fallback alternative in your bootstrap code. In our application we check if we can use the spl_autoload_register function and if we can we do, if we can't we use the __autoload function but direct both of them to same class.

Comment: @ThiefMaster In all my time, I've yet to observe a shared hosting provider that had the SPL disabled: for that particular extension, your argument is very weak indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This works!!!

```
class ClassAutoloader {
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
    }
    private function loader($className) {
        echo 'Trying to load ', $className, ' via ', __METHOD__, "()\n";
        include $className . '.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Before PHP 5.3 SPL was optional and thus possibly not available - and especially on shared hosting you don't necessarily have a recent PHP version. Besides that, the code would become pretty nasty (registering tons of equal autoload functions) when creating more than one instance of your class.

Comment: The global `__autoload` function always works. You just need to include whatever file contains that function for it to work.

Comment: I doing OOP and don't want to have a function sit out there and it just create mess...

Comment: This sounds like you misunderstood something. The purpose of OOP is **not** shoving everything into a class no matter if it's appropriate or not. In Java you only do that because the language requires it. Use classes for things where creating instances makes sense.